# ¿Que tan importantes son las etiquetas article y figure?

Tags: html5

Tengo entendido que estas (Y otras etiquetas 'wrap' parecidas) sirven para maximizar compatibilidad con dispositivos mobiles, sin embargo, habia aprendido que para esto tenemos cosas como el responsive web design entre otros. Entonces, ¿Que tan importantes son estas en un documento web? ¿Da igual usarlas o no? ¿Todas se pueden substituir por css?

Gracias!

Comment: Falta incluir información sobre lo buscado/investigado sobre el tema. Para más detalle véase [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad, `<article>`y `<figure>` [aparecidos a partir de HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/HTML/HTML5) **no fueron creados en función de la *responsividad*, sino en función de organizar mejor el contenido de los documentos HTML**. De hecho, la documentación no hace referencia al tema de la *responsividad* cuando explica el sentido de estas etiquetas.

### article

Pertenece al grupo de elementos de HTML5 que sirven para el **Seccionamiento del contenido** los cuales, [de acuerdo a la documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento):

> Permiten organizar los contenidos del documento en partes lógicas. Usa
>   los elementos de seccionado para crear una descripción amplia de los
>   contenidos de tu página, incluyendo el encabezado y pie de página y
>   elementos para identificar secciones.

Entre esos elementos se encuentran por ejemplo `<section>, <header>, <footer>` ... y otros.

[MDN define el elemento `<article>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/article) del siguiente modo:

> El Elemento article de HTML () representa una composición
>   auto-contenida en un documento, página, una aplicación o en el sitio,
>   que se destina a distribuir de forma independiente o reutilizable, por
>   ejemplo, en la sindicación. Podría ser un mensaje en un foro, un
>   artículo de una revista o un periódico, una entrada de blog, un
>   comentario de un usuario, un widget interactivo o gadget, o cualquier
>   otro elemento independiente del contenido.
>
> Notas de uso:
>
> - Cuando los elementos  están anidados, los internos representan artículos relacionados con el exterior. Por ejemplo, los
>     comentarios de un blog pueden ser elementos  anidados al que
>     representa la entrada del blog.
> - Los datos del autor de un elemento  pueden ser proporcionados a través del elemento , pero no se aplica a
>     los elementos  anidados.
> - La fecha de publicación y el tiempo de un elemento  pueden ser descritos con el atributo pubdate atributo de un elemento .

#### Especificación de article

[Aquí puedes ver la especificación de `<article>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-article-element) y también varios ejemplos de cómo usarlo.

---

### figure

Figúrate que `<figure>` pertenece en HTML5 al grupo de elementos que tratan el **Contenido del texto**, los cuales, [siempre de acuerdo a la doc de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento), sirven:

> Para organizar bloques o secciones de contenido colocados entre los
>   tags de apertura `<body>` y cierre. **Es importante para la
>   accessibilidad y el SEO, que estos elementos se identifiquen con el
>   objetivo o la estructura de ese contenido**.

Hermanos de `<figure>`, serían los ya conocidos `<div>, <p>, <li>` ... y otros.

Como verás, cuando la doc [define a `<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/figure), tampoco hace referencia a la *responsividad*.

> El elemento HTML `<figure>` representa contenido independiente, a
>   menudo con un título. Si bien se relaciona con el flujo principal, su
>   posición es independiente de éste. Por lo general, se trata de una
>   imagen, una ilustración, un diagrama, un fragmento de código, o un
>   esquema al que se hace referencia en el texto principal, pero que se
>   puede mover a otra página o a un apéndice sin que afecte al flujo
>   principal.
>
> Notas de uso:
>
> - Al ser una seccionador raíz, el esbozo del contenido del elemento `<figure>` está excluido del esbozo principal del documento.
> - Un título puede estar asociado con el elemento `<figure>` mediante la inserción de un `<figcaption>` en su interior (como el primero o el
>     último hijo).

#### Especificación de figure

[Aquí puedes ver la especificación de `<figure>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-figure-element) y también varios ejemplos de cómo usarlo.

---

### ¿Da igual usarlas o no?

En buena práctica de programación **no da igual usarlas o no**. Si existen son para algo y, si quieres ser un buen programador, entonces cumple las normas. Si escribes un documento HTML5 que contiene un `<article>` o una `<figure>` entonces etiquétalos como tal.

Buena práctica de programación significa también ayudar a que las páginas que escribas tengan un mejor y mayor impacto a nivel de SEO, y para esto también usar las etiquetas adecuadas es importante.

Digamos que un documento con faltas de ortografía podría ser legible, pero no es lo mismo que si está escrito correctamente. Lo mismo pasa con nuestros documentos HTML escritos con las etiquetas correspondientes o no.

### ¿Todas se pueden sustituir por CSS?

Sustituir... pues no. ¿Para qué? Lo que sí se pueden es **alcanzar** usando CSS para aplicarles reglas de estilo. ¿Acaso sustituimos a sus hermanos por CSS, me refiero a los `<p>, <div>, <ul>, <section>` ..., ¿no los sustituimos verdad? sino que usamos CSS para aplicarles estilo. Pues hemos de darle el mismo trato a estos **hermanos más pequeños que acaban de nacer.**

### Un anexo interesante

Esto sería un diagrama decisional que nos ayuda a tener algunos criterios para decidir cuándo usar los elementos de HTML tomando en cuenta las novedades de HTML5.
Prometo traducirlo más adelante si es necesario, pero se entiende.

[image: diagrama de uso de etiquetas HTML5]

Comment: Gracias, me ha quedado mas claro, ahora me suena a necedad lo de substituirlas por css jeje